# Autostart my python program in Raspbian with rc.local does not work

Tags: python, raspbian, autostart

So I have a program that I want to autostart in Raspberry Pi. My program is supposed to grab some api-info online and then display it on a little screen.  I've added these lines to rc.local:

```
sudo python ./home/pi/Documents/Skanetrafiken_projekt/testStart.py &
sudo python ./home/pi/Documents/Skanetrafiken_projekt/main.py &
```

The testStart.py just tests the display and it works fine, the screen lights up when the Raspberry Pi boots up. So that works. The main.py won't work at all however. In the beginning of the main code I even put the same code as in testStart.py, just to see if the display lights up, but it doesn't. So that is super weird to me.

Could it be something about that the main.py will connect to internet? I tried setting "Waiting of network to boot" in the raspi-config settings, but that didn't help.

The main works fine when I run in manually. I also tried to start with cron, but that didn't work. I don't have that much experience.

And ideas?

Answer (score 0):

try using `sudo crontab -e` and then adding `@reboot sudo python /path/to/your/script.py` this then should run your script every time you boot up.

Answer (score 0):

I tested running the script from the prompt rather than directly from the python script, and I guess the prompt uses another compilator or something because now I got many errors that I didn't get before.  Including that I have to include the line

`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

for it to understand my comments. So now it works anyway.